# Hibernate unidirectional one to many association - why is a join table better?

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, foreign-keys, associations

In this document (scroll down to the Unidirectional section):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-collections

it says that a unidirectional one-to-many association with a join table is much preferred to just using a foreign key column in the owned entity. My question is, why is it much preferred?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092611/why-is-it-recommended-to-avoid-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-on-a-forei

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Consider the situation where the owned entity type can also be owned by another parent entity type. Do you put foreign key references in the owned table to both parent tables? What if you have three parent types? It just doesn't scale to large designs.

A join-table decouples the join, so that the owned table has no knowledge of the parent table(s), allowing the design to scale elegantly.

Comment: See the difference of internal SQL operations being invoked in join table and foreign key at http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333198/418439

Answer (score 11):

If the child entity has only ever one parent type, then there is no need for a join table. 
I've done this with JPA (with a hibernate impl.).

Advantages: 
One less table.
Perhaps better performance.
No "what is this table for?" type questions.

Disadvantage: 
From the OO perspective there is an additional dependency between child and parent introduced. In practice this is probably not such a big deal, since the relationship is private in the child.

```
e.g. 
parent:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKey(name = "name")
private Map children;

child:
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Parent parent;
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on the dis-advantage

Comment: Just note that with JPA 2.0 the reference on the child to the parent is no longer necessary. Just use the @JoinColumn annotation on the parent.

Comment: @EdyBourne - Do you know what version of Hibernate added support for that?