# Is it possible to optimize SQL Generated by Hibernate for OneToMany relationship with JoinTable?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, join

I'm using JPA with Hibernate 4 as provider and I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="customers_phones",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_customer")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_phone")}
            )
    private List<Phone> phones;

    .. Getters/Setters ..
}

@Entity
public class Phone {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String number;

    .. Getters/Setters ..
}
```

And I have the following JPQL:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.phones p WHERE p.id = :phone
```

For which Hibernate is generating the following SQL:

```
select
    customer0_.id as id1_0_,
    customer0_.name as name2_0_ 
from
    Customer customer0_ 
inner join
    customers_phones phones1_ 
        on customer0_.id=phones1_.id_customer 
inner join
    Phone phone2_ 
        on phones1_.id_phone=phone2_.id 
where
    phone2_.id=?
```

I'd like Hibernate to generate the SQL like follows (i.e. without joinning table 'Phone'):

```
select
    customer0_.id as id1_0_,
    customer0_.name as name2_0_ 
from
    Customer customer0_ 
inner join
    customers_phones phones1_ 
        on customer0_.id=phones1_.id_customer 
where
    phones1_.id_phone=?
```

I know I could map a new entity to the join table 'customers_phones' associate it to Customer and use it in the query or I could use native SQL instead of JPQL, but I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this (without changing entity model and still using JPQL), maybe some Hibernate-specific Query Hint?

Comment: Why are you using a JoinTable for a OneToMany relationship? It is simpler to use a standard OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship.

Comment: What if you use `SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE :phone IN elements(c.phones)`? If Hibernate expects an object instead of ID, you can still call `em.getReference()`.

Comment: @SpartanElite, I asked myself the same, but I can't change database schema. The application runs with a legacy database and this OneToMany relationship was designed that way. I've read about it and noticed there are some [arguable] reasons to model OneToMany using JoinTable, as you can see here:

- [1] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307203/hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-why-is-a-join-table-better)  
- [2] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092611/why-is-it-recommended-to-avoid-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-on-a-forei)

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel, the query you suggested removes the join to table 'Phones', but it's a less intuitive jpql and still the generated SQL (as follows) has higher cost than the single "customers join customers_phones" that I expected from Hibernate.

    `select
 customer0_.id as id1_0_,
 customer0_.name as name2_0_ 
from
 Customer customer0_ 
where
 ? in (
   select
    phones1_.id_phone 
   from
    customers_phones phones1_ 
   where
    customer0_.id=phones1_.id_customer
  )`

Sorry but I don't know how to format this comments.