# OneToMany - what are  the differences between join table and foreign key?

Tags: mapping, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, one-to-many

There is the possibility to disable the `@OneToMany` relationship join table with the `@JoinColumn` annotation. The default is a join table.

What are the advantages and disadvantages for a production system for example?
When should I use a join table and when not?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to use relation table in 1:n relation. Ask more precisely.

Comment: As a default the @OneToMany mapping creates a join table. I don´t know why the default is not mapping with foreign key...

Comment: My guess is that that its not for performance or draw backs, but because JPA generally assumes that all fields within a table are mapped within the corresponding entity.  This is an edge case since it is more common to have a OneToMany with a ManyToOne back.  With the unidirectional OneToMany using joincolumn, it requires that the child table have a foreign key, but the child entity not have a reference to its parent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default `@OneToMany` will create a join table only if you'll use **unidirectional relationship**.

In other words, if you have `Employee` and `Project` entities and the `Employee` entity is defined as follows *(assume there is no `orm.xml` entries for these entities)*:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    // ...

    @OneToMany
    Set<Project> projects;
}

@Entity
public class Project {
    // ...
}
```

the JPA provider **will create a join table** (notice there is no `mappedBy` attribute in `@OneToMany` annotation as there is no reference to `Employee` entity from the `Project`).

On the other hand, if you'll use bidirectional relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    Set<Project> projects;
}

@Entity
public class Project {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    Employee employee;
}
```

The join table will not be used, as there "many" side will be used to store the foreign key for this relationship.

However, you can force to use join table even in cases when you have bidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship with defined `mappedBy` attribute. You can achieve it using [`@JoinTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation on the owning side of the relationship.

There is also a possibility, as you've mentioned, to use `@JoinColumn` in case where join table would be used by default (unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship).

It's best to test the FK and join table performance difference for yourself. I can just guess that less joins (in this case: FK) seems to have better performance.

Moreover, sometimes the DBA defines the database schema and you just need to fit your mappings to the existing schema. Then you have no choice over FK or join table - that's why you have a choice.

Comment: Hibernate is clear about it: "A unidirectional one to many with join table is much preferred. This association is described through an @JoinTable." http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168 section "2.2.5.3.1.3. Unidirectional with join table"

Answer (score 0):

Join tables are needed for polymorphisms. E.g., if Employee and Manager links the same project and they are mapped with one-table-per-class strategy, at the relational DB level, the only way to know that project( id = 1, emp_id = 10 ) refers to a manager is to put emp_id in the manager_2_employee table. If one is not in such a situation, then emp_id can go directly into project.

Comment: See advantages of join table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307203/hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-why-is-a-join-table-better

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above, by default hibernate goes for join table.
This results in better db normalization.

If having a choice, JoinColumn gives better performance over the join table as need for the joining of an extra table in the SQL Query is removed.