# How to join two tables which has many to one relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

I have two tables and they got many to one relationship. Below entity creates a join column called school_id. Problem is project manager said never use join column but use join table.

I think when I use join table it will create a new table like "school_student_relationship" and will store relationship with this table.Why do I need to use join table instead of join column? Is it about performance or something else?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
    private School school;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "school_id")
    private String schoolId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "school", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student> students= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: Ask your manager. He should be able to answer this question. If he can't, then you should probably stick to what JPA experts/designers decided to be the default for ManyToOne, i.e. a join column.

Comment: this may be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572554/onetomany-what-are-the-differences-between-join-table-and-foreign-key