# Unidirectional One-To-Many mapping with join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

Why does unidirectional One-To-Many mapping with join table have better performance than unidirectional One-To-Many mapping with foreign key on target table?

I read on some docs that it's advisable to use join table strategy when mapping unidirectional one-to-many association for performance purposes. I'd like to know the reason of why this approach brings better performance than the others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate unidirectional one to many association - why is a join table better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307203/hibernate-unidirectional-one-to-many-association-why-is-a-join-table-better)

Comment: It looks like to be duplicated, but it doesn't. The referenced link tells about better design.

My doubt is about performance issues. I mean if I use join table as unidirectional mapping strategy, will it cause less hits in database when querying, inserting and removing elements in association?

Comment: The point is that this choice is not based n performance, but on clean design. I expect the performance to be worse, given the all reads and writes need to be done on two tables rather than one, and that an additional join is needed. But you can only tell by measuring, and it depends on the use-case.