# JPA unidirectional @OneToMany performance

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with `unidirectional @OneToMany Lazy` relationship. When I try to add a child, it seems like Hibernate 4 (my JPA provider) actually performs

1. Select query
2. Delete all children with that parent id on join table
3. Reinsert back all and the new child on join table

How to make Hibernate to just insert the child I wish, without changing my relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship will use a join table, it will perform operation as my question. If you are using JPA2 and do not use polymorphic on parent, you may add `@JoinColumn`, which will create foreign key on children table instead of another join table. JPA provider then will not perform delete and reinsert again.

Answer (score 2):

making relationship bidirectional will solve your problem. you can read some information [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/hibernate-mapped-collections.html)

Comment: I can't change it to bidirectional, as what I have stated.